# How can I get diff() to work here? [ I cannt use lag() or lead()]

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the increase in life expectancy for each country, but I cannot get the diff() function to work here. I also tried the lag/lead functions but I cannot use that. Any advise is appreciated.

```
library(gapminder)
gm <- gapminder
inclife <- gm %>%
   drop_na(lifeExp)%>%
   group_by(country) %>%
   select(country, year, lifeExp) %>%
   mutate(inc = diff(lifeExp))
```

This is the error I got

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `inc = diff(lifeExp)`.
✖ `inc` must be size 12 or 1, not 11.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: country = "Afghanistan".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Why can you not use lead/lag? That seems like an odd restriction if you are using dplyr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append a `NA` or another value, since `diff` will provide a vector of length n-1, and `mutate` requires that the number of observations does not change.

```
inclife <- gm %>%
   drop_na(lifeExp)%>%
   group_by(country) %>%
   select(country, year, lifeExp) %>%
   mutate(inc = c(NA,diff(lifeExp)))
```